# Ruby called a collection of blocks

Tags: ruby

Assume I have built an array of callable objects by doing

```
callables = []
callables << block1
callables << block2
callables << block3
callables << block4
```

Later I want to call these blocks. I understand I can do

```
callables.each { |block| block.call }
```

but I am wondering if I could make it even simpler by calling something like

```
callables.each :call
```

I have tried the code above but got ArgumentError. Does ruby support this kind of syntax?

Comment: You can do `callables.each(&:call)` The & calls `to_proc` on the object, and passes it as a block to the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try :

```
callables.each &:call
```

`Array#each` don't accept any arguments. That's why, when you write `callables.each :call`, `:call` the symbol is passing to the method `each` as an argument. But when you prefixed `:call` with `&`, `each` knows that you are giving it a *block* as an argument, so it will work.

Comment: It's worth noting that `each(&:call)` is a special case and is passed in as a block argument. Basically the `&` calls `to_proc` on `:call`, turning it into a procedure.

Comment: @WeiMa Don't get hung up on the internals. `each(&:call)` is the same as `each(&:call.to_proc)` or `each { |x| x.call }`. There's no need to call `to_proc` manually. Remember Ruby is highly object-oriented, so method calls are almost always made on the object, not with the object as an argument. For example, it's `"string".upcase`, not `upcase("string")`